Разделение значений из одного столбца на 2
Есть следующий файл Excel вида:

В питоне выглядит также:

Как я могу преобразовать данные таким образом, чтобы цифры, которые идут в столбце с именами образовали еще один столбец?
Или же сделать сортировку, чтобы для каждого имени удовлетворялось условие, что есть посещение в 8,9 и 10 месяце с помощью регулярных выражений?

"Могу я преобразовать ..." - можете! Но наверное вы хотели спросить КАК это сделать. Отредактируйте вопрос пожалуйста (кнопка "править").

И покажите, какую структуру данных вы хотите получить на выходе.

@CrazyElf, в целом я хочу получить список тех людей, у которых есть посещение в 8, 9 и 10 месяцах. В принципе структура может остаться такая же, только должна быть очищена от людей, у которых есть посещения, например, только в 8 и 10 месяцах.

Можно не подкармливать питона, всё решается одной птичкой в Excel:


На счёт выборки только самых активных посетителей, то вопрос тоже можно решить в Excel.

Нужно добавить колонку Condition и ввести в неё формулу:
C2 и размножить вниз =((SUM(($A$2:$A$30=A2)*($B$2:$B$30=8))>0)+(SUM(($A$2:$A$30=A2)*($B$2:$B$30=9))>0)+(SUM(($A$2:$A$30=A2)*($B$2:$B$30=10))>0))=3

Остальное показано на снимке экрана.

Сделал сводную таблицу из данных, но получается не как у вас.
Просто с экселем я совсем не лады - https://postimg.cc/Mfp4RHLF

Таблица остаётся как была, переделывать не нужно, только поставить птичку в свойствах сводной таблицы.

Повторил все ваши действия:
1- таблица до изменений - https://postimg.cc/bZVv2SFK
2 - изменения - https://postimg.cc/47V4MLNg
3 - таблица после изменений - https://postimg.cc/8sdPm00d
Но результат как у вас не получается :(

Нужно стараться. Проверьте формирование таблицы (панель справа).

Порядок такой: 1) добавить колонку Condition; 2) сделать новую таблицу как показано на последнем снимке экрана на панели справа (всё в точности); 3) отфильтровать таблицу по Condition=TRUE (ячейка G1). Конец. Сначала потренируйтесь на тестовых данных.
